# Configure NetCDF on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, netcdf

I'm working on a `C++` project which handles weather data in `NetCDF` format. I downloaded the `NetCDF` binaries from [this link](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/netcdf/ftp/netCDF4.3.3.1-NC4-32.exe) and installed it.

Also configured the VS project as follows:

> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories = C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\netCDF 4.3.3.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\netCDF 4.3.3.1\lib;
>
> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories = C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\netCDF 4.3.3.1\include
>
> Linker -> Input = netcdf.lib

But the problem is I cannot access the `netCDF` namespace.

```
using namespace netCDF;  //gives an error
```

But accessing header files doesn't make any trouble

```
#include <netcdf.h>   //no error
```

Can someone help me out on this..........

Answer (score 1):

NetCDF is a c-library, it has no namespaces, as such you should just remove "using namespace netCDF".

Comment: Nope. It supports C++ as well. I referred this code http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/programs/SimpleXyRd.cpp

Comment: Still does not change the fact that the file you included is the c library which has no namespaces, take a good hard look at your include directive, and the include directive in your linked sample.